# How to restart any crashed server in linux?

Tags: linux, selenium, restart

I have a server where i run selenium-server with a command:
`xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar`. Now it crash some times and i need some tool that can restart selenium while i'm looking for a reason of crashes. 
Generally it's nice to have a pattern that can be applied to other programs.